# PHP errors Class inside function inside class.. wait what? lost

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258875/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-query-on-a-non-object-in)

I have a class file, lets call it 'stuff'

```
Stuff.class
```

inside there is a class

```
class  Stuff {
```

and in there I have a public static function

```
   public static function morestuff() {

}
```

Inside I need to call another function for a query

```
$q="Select from contacts where id =". $this->$db->escapeVal($ID)".";
```

But I get errors.

```
$q="Select from contacts where id =". escapeVal($ID)".";
```

Returns

```
Call to undefined function escapeVal()


$q="Select from contacts where id =". $db->escapeVal($ID)".";
```

Returns

```
Call to a member function escapeVal() on a non-object


$q="Select from contacts where id =". $this->$db->escapeVal($ID)".";
```

Returns

```
Using $this when not in object context
```

So what do I put?

EDIT:

A similar function in the same file has the following code

```
'id' = '" . $this->db->escapeVal($this->_Id) . "'
```

However when I try to use this code in my mysql query I get the following error

```
Using $this when not in object context
```

Comment: Probably unrelated to the problem, but you need `$this->db` and not `$this->$db`.

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed that also.

Comment: Instead of alternating between code and English, present uninterrupted, complete, concise, representative [sample code](http://sscce.org/) so that it can be given directly to PHP and run as-is. If you need to comment, use comments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object PHP Help](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4463441/), [Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7258875/), [Another “Yet another call to a member function function() on a non-object”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3568785/)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `$db` is a global variable, so try

```
public static function morestuff() {
      global $db;

      $q="Select from contacts where id =". $db->escapeVal($ID);

}
```

If the function is in the same class and is also static you will call it like

```
self::escapeVal($ID);
```

Comment: I suggest you inject it as an argument, and not use global!

Comment: @Truth you should suggest that to the poster and not penalize me for that!

Comment: I updated the question with info you might find useful
@SabeenMalik I just upvoted you, don't worry

Comment: @SabeenMalik: No, **You** are the one providing the solution, so **You** should be pointing what seems the correct solution in your eyes. If using `global` seems correct to you, then you definitely deserve the downvote. If not, correct your post and I will remove my vote. That simple :)

Comment: @Truth you 'suggested' not using global but from the looks of it you are are forcing it not just suggesting it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not understanding the concept of OOP. `$this` is a variable which refers to the current object (or **this object**). Meaning:

```
class Test {
    public function __construct() { //Called when object is instantiated
        var_dump($this);
    }
}
$test = new Test();
```

You'll get something similar to

```
object(Test)#1 (0) { }
```

You cannot use `$this` outside of a class method. It just doesn't work that way.

About the error you're having, try to figure out where is the database connection stored. That connection should either be passed to the **object** for storing as a field, or directly to the **method** to work with it internally.

Programming isn't about copy/pasting code that works.

Answer (score 0):

Because your function is static, the variable `$this` won't exist inside it.

To solve your problem, there are 2 solutions:

1. Make `$db` a static variable, meaning it will be the same in every instance.
2. Remove the `static` keyword from the function `morestuff()`. In this case you will need to make an instance of the class in order to make a call to `morestuff()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Stuff->db->escapeVal($id)
```

started to work. So happy i got it to work, Thank you very one.